# Polar decomposition of invertible elements in a unital C$ ^{*} $-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $ A $ is a unital C$ ^{*} $-algebra and $ a $ is invertible, then

1. $ a = u|a| $ for a unique unitary element $ u $ of $ A $.
2. If $ \| a \| = \| a^{-1} \| = 1 $, what can you say about $ |a| $?

I don’t know how to start!

Comment: You can just say that $ A $ is a C$ ^{*} $-algebra.

Comment: Set $u:=a/|a|$ and show that $u$ is a unitary element of $A$. The rest follows from Haskell Curry's answer.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh do you mean put $u=a|a|^{-1}$ ??

Comment: @edab12: Yes, your expression is more correct.

Comment: @edab12: As $ |a| $ must be invertible, we have $ u = a |a|^{-1} $. Hence, $ u $ is uniquely determined. To show that $ u $ is unitary, simply observe that $$ u^{\ast} u = |a|^{-1} a^{\ast} a |a|^{-1} = |a|^{-1} |a|^{2} |a|^{-1} = \mathbf{1}_{A} $$ and $$ u u^{\ast} = a |a|^{-1} |a|^{-1} a^{\ast} = a |a|^{-2} a^{\ast} = a a^{-1} (a^{*})^{-1} a^{\ast} = \mathbf{1}_{A}. $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will make use of the following basic result from the theory of Banach algebras.

> **Theorem 1** Let $ A $ be a Banach algebra. If $ x \in A $ is invertible, then $ 0 \notin {\sigma_{A}}(x) $ and
>   $$
> {\sigma_{A}}(x^{-1}) = \left\{ \frac{1}{\lambda} ~ \Bigg| ~ \lambda \in {\sigma_{A}}(x) \right\}.
> $$

We also need the following theorem from the theory of C$ ^{*} $-algebras.

> **Theorem 2** Let $ A $ be a C$ ^{*} $-algebra. Then for any **normal element** $ x $ of $ A $, we have
>   $$
> {r_{A}}(x) = \| x \|_{A},
> $$
>   where $ {r_{A}}(x) $ denotes the spectral radius of $ x $.

---

Let $ A $ be a C$ ^{*} $-algebra. Let $ a \in A $ be invertible, and suppose that $ \| a \|_{A} = \| a^{-1} \|_{A} = 1 $. Then
\begin{align}
{\sigma_{A}}(|a|) &= {\sigma_{A}} \left( \sqrt{a^{*} a} \right) \\
                  &= \sqrt{{\sigma_{A}}(a^{*} a)} \quad
                     (\text{By the Spectral Mapping Theorem applied to $ a^{*} a $.}) \\
                  &= \{ 1 \}. \quad (\clubsuit)
\end{align}

> *Proof of $ (\clubsuit) $*:
>   Firstly, observe that $ {\sigma_{A}}(a^{*} a) \subseteq [0,\infty) $. Next, using the C$ ^{*} $-condition and the fact that involution in a C$ ^{*} $-algebra is an isometry, we have
>   $$
> \| a^{*} a \|_{A} = \| (a^{*}) (a^{*})^{*} \|_{A}
>                   = \| a^{*} \|_{A}^{2}
>                   = \| a \|_{A}^{2}
>                   = 1
> $$
>   and
>   \begin{align}
> \| (a^{*} a)^{-1} \|_{A} &= \| a^{-1} (a^{*})^{-1} \|_{A} \\
>                          &= \| a^{-1} (a^{-1})^{*} \|_{A} \\
>                          &= \| a^{-1} \|_{A}^{2} \\
>                          &= 1.
> \end{align}
>   By Theorems $ 1 $ and $ 2 $, we therefore obtain $ {\sigma_{A}}(a^{*} a) = \{ 1 \} $.

Let us now work with the Continuous Functional Calculus corresponding to the self-adjoint element $ a^{*} a $. As $ {\sigma_{A}}(a^{*} a) = \{ 1 \} $, applying both the constant function $ 1 $ and the identity function to $ a^{*} a $ yields
$$
\mathbf{1}_{A} = a^{*} a.
$$
Therefore, $ |a| := \sqrt{a^{*} a} = \mathbf{1}_{A} $ and $ a = u|a| = u $.

---

**Conclusion:** If $ a \in A $ is invertible and $ \| a \|_{A} = \| a^{-1} \|_{A} = 1 $, then $ |a| = \mathbf{1}_{A} $ and $ a $ is unitary.

---

**Note:** In the argument above, we first proved that $ a^{*} a = \mathbf{1}_{A} $, then used polar decomposition to deduce that $ a $ is unitary and hence $ a a^{*} = \mathbf{1}_{A} $. However, we could have proven directly that $ a $ is unitary by performing the argument with $ a^{*} $ instead of $ a $, as the given conditions already imply that $ a^{*} $ is invertible and that $ \| a^{*} \|_{A} = \| (a^{*})^{-1} \|_{A} = 1 $. Once again, we have to use the fact that involution in a C$ ^{*} $-algebra is an isometry.

Comment: Thank you very much, but does this mean that $|a|$ must be the identity of $A$ ?

Comment: in Gerard Murphy's : $C^{*}$ Algebras and Operator Theory, page 73 , the second condition holds iff $a$ is unitary !

Comment: @edab12: Yes, $ |a| $ must be the identity.

Comment: Yes, I didn't use the polar decomposition to prove that $a$ is unitary, Thank you for ur help!