# Question on unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, unitary-matrices

If two complex numbers $a, b$ are such that $|a| = |b|$ then there is a unitary complex number $e^{i\theta}$ such that
$$a = b e^{i\theta}$$

Does this hold also for matrices? My best guess is that we need to check the determinants: if $|\det A| = |\det B|$ there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A = BU$.

Is that true? I think it is true if they also share a basis of left singular vectors by simply looking at a SVD of the two matrices, but I wanted to better understand the statement above.

Comment: $A=BU$ for some unitary matrix $U$ if and only if $B^{-1}A$ is unitary. The relevant matrix factorization which generalizes the polar form of complex numbers is the polar decomposition.

Comment: It is also true that $A = BU$ for some unitary matrix $U$ if and only if $AA^T = BB^T$, regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are invertible. In a sense, the "correct" analog to the absolute value $|a|$ of $a$ in this context is the matrix $\sqrt{A^TA}$ corresponding to $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think this is what I'm looking for! I guess that $\cdot^T$ means adjoint right? I can't come up with a proof for it though, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy Yes. I actually should have used $\cdot ^*$ since I meant the adjoint (AKA conjugate-transpose) rather than the simple transpose of the matrix. There is a quick proof using the SVD

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy By the way, you might find this interesting: the "polar-decomposition" of matrices consists of taking a matrix $A$ and expressing it in the form $A = PU$, where $P$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $U$ is unitary. If you want to make this more analogous to the expression $a = be^{i\theta}$, it is actually possible to find a Hermitian (self-adjoint) matrix $H$ such that $U = e^{i H}$, where $e^{M}$ denotes the matrix exponential of $M$. In terms of the SVD of $A$, we have $P = V\Sigma V^*$ and $U = VW^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two matrices $A,B \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$, there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A = BU$ if and only if $AA^* = BB^*$, where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $A$.

In terms of singular vectors, $AA^* = BB^*$ will hold if and only if $A,B$ have a common basis of left singular vectors and the same (corresponding) singular values.

Here is a quick proof of this using the SVD. Write $A = V_A\Sigma_AW_A^*$ and $B = V_B \Sigma_B W_B^*$, where the matrices $V_A,W_A,V_B,W_B$ are unitary and the matrices $\Sigma_A,\Sigma_B$ are diagonal with non-negative diagonal entries.

First, the easy direction: suppose that $A = BU$. Then
$$
AA^* = (BU)(BU)^* = BUU^*B^* = BIB^* = BB^*.
$$

Conversely, suppose that $AA^* = BB^*$. In terms of the SVD, this gives us
$$
V_A\Sigma_A^2 V_A^* = V_B\Sigma_B^2 W_B^*
$$
This is an equality of two positive semidefinite matrices. Because positive semidefinite matrices have a unique positive semidefinite square root, we can "take the square root of both sides" to conclude that
$$
V_A \Sigma_A V_A^* = V_B\Sigma_B V_B^*.
$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
A &= V_A \Sigma_A W_A^* 
\\ & = V_A \Sigma_A (V_A^*V_A)W_A^*
\\ & = (V_A \Sigma_A V_A^*)(V_AW_A^*)
\\ & = (V_B\Sigma_B V_B^*)(V_AW_A^*)
\\ & = V_B\Sigma_B (V_B^* V_AW_A^*)
\\ & = V_B\Sigma_B(W_B^*W_B) (V_B^* V_AW_A^*)
\\ & = (V_B\Sigma_BW_B^*)\underbrace{(W_B V_B^* V_AW_A^*)}_{U} = BU.
\end{align}
Because $U = W_B V_B^* V_AW_A^*$ is a product of unitary matrices, it is unitary.

Comment: Thank you, very accurate. This works for any unital C* algebra, correct? If A, B are elements of some C* algebra, then U will be a unitary element of that algebra?

Comment: Yes, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319126/81360) for instance.